# Google Maps API on Squarespace

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, squarespace

I'm using Squarespace to build my website and want to insert a custom map from google maps javascript api. I've already gotten google api key.

I've followed steps as below :

What I'm trying to archive is just to show a google map on my web.

**Step 1**: Insert a embed block for html

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

**Step 2**: insert javascript in page header

```
<script  type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my-key&sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

**Step 3** : in custom css section

```
#map_canvas 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

But the codes I put on Squarespace didn't work. How should I do?
Here the link to my webpage on SquareSpace

[Your Site Title](https://sayaka-tamura-fcsy.squarespace.com/)

Thanks!!

Comment: Try fixed value of width and height. `width: 500px; height: 500px;`. Rest of your code seams fine

Comment: Can I ask why you are going this route when Squarespace already has a built in integration for Google Maps? From your example here, you're not plotting any data so the need for a custom Google map is not really relevant. Am I missing something? If you need a multi-location map, your code will quite a bit more complex in order to grab the data from Squarespace and plot it to the map...

Comment: @jasonbarone

Sorry for the really late reply.
The reason why I'm gonna go this route is because I'd like to make a multi-location map later as you said. 
If you have time, I hope you would tell me the way to put to Squarespace.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

LoL, u put the script at a very wrong place i think.

1st. put your script, all of it after `</body>`

2nd. you need a cover for your maps `<div>` like a wrapper or so to put it in center. and using a cover/wrapper div you can manipulate the size and the shape.

3rd. i don't know `id="maps_canvas"`. because from google i got this                 `<div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:100%;width:100%; position:static'>`, it was gmap_canvas. and put style in it to make them fit with your cover/wrapper div.

easier way: http://embedgooglemaps.com/en/
perhaps it'll help. :)

Comment: Name of the `div`  can be anything 'gmap` or `map` or any random name.

Comment: yup indeed, but ever you use this http://embedgooglemaps.com/en/ it will help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks, all of u guys! It will be a great help for me!!

river rhun>

Where can I see '</body>' code?
I tried to find where '</body>' tag is at each setting page (page header, custom css, code-injection)
But I couldn't find it...

And, I hope I could show full width-map on my website finally.
So I will not be able to use the link you sent for embedding map.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I changed in my code as below :

**Step 1**: Insert a **code** block for html <-- it was not embed block, but code block. I mistyped before.

```
<div id="mapWrapper">
    <div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:100%;width:100%; position:static'>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**Step 2**: insert javascript in page header.

I change only ID name from '**map_canvas**' to '**gmap_canvas**'

```
<script  type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my-key&sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

**Step 3** : in custom css section.

Changed ID name from '**map_canvas**' to '**mapWrapper**', then set another size.

```
#mapWrapper 
        {
         width: 750px;
         height: 500px;
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px
       }
```

I tried to put most of everything people advised me, but still the map doesn't come up on my site.
Is there something wrong yet?

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing with [my site](http://www.marionfranklin.org/map/).

What I did differently is not put my #map-canvas within a wrapper. While previewing your site, are you able to find your gmap_canvas with the inspect view? It may be that the content is there, just not displaying properly.

My code:

The following is in the page header code injection box. Note that a large bit of this code (and I don't remember which parts since I don't know JS) is just to keep the pin centered on different screen sizes.

```
<style type="text/css">
       html, body, #map-canvas { 
         height: 400px; 
         width 960px; 
         margin: 0; 
         padding: 0;}         

      #banner-area-wrapper {
        display: none;
      }

     </style>
     <script type="text/javascript"
       src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key&callback=initMap">
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function detectBrowser() {
   var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
   var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map-canvas");

   if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
     mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
     mapdiv.style.height = '100%';
   } else {
     mapdiv.style.width = '600px';
     mapdiv.style.height = '800px';
   }
 }
       function initialize() {

 var myLatLng = {lat: 39.910073, lng: -82.965509};
         var mapOptions = {
           center: myLatLng,
           zoom: 14,
           panControl: false,
           mapTypeControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
             zoomControlOptions: {
             style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER},
           streetViewControl: false
         };
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
             mapOptions);

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
           mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Opportunity Center'
  });

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center); 
});
       }
```

On the page, I have a code block, with the following in it:

```
 <div id="map-canvas" style="width:90%;margin:auto;"></div>
```

Note that I did not put my #map-canvas inside a wrapper, nor include anything in the custom CSS.

I made a quick dummy site, and replicated your failure to show the map, but I don't know quite enough about Squarespace to say exactly why. I'd start with copying my code and see if that works for you - seems like the big difference is your wrapper around the canvas.